# Retrieve guest cart using token in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, token

When you create a guest cart you will receive a token that may look like this ***"696EreQdYt2AAtEceQsHfD2gxGyWFodG"*** and you can use it to retrieve a guest cart that has an id number.

I know how to retrieve the guest cart using the id. My question is, can I retrieve the guest cart using the token (programmatically)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this dependency to your class constructor:

```
private $quoteIdMaskFactory;

public function __construct(
   ....
   \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
   ....
) {
   ....
   $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
   ....
}
```

Then your can retrieve the cart it like this:

```
$maskedId = '696EreQdYt2AAtEceQsHfD2gxGyWFodG';
$quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($maskedId, 'masked_id');
if ($quoteIdMask->getId()) {
    $cartId = $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();
} else {
    //cart does not exist.
}
```

Comment: You are faster then  me:)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: how will we get maskID in any interface ?